# MatLab floating point comparison

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand the `while` statement in MatLab so this is what I did:

```
i=0;
while i<=20
  disp(i)
  i=i+1;
end
```

and as I expected, MatLab displayed numbers 0-20. However with this one:

```
j=0;
while j<=2
  disp(j)
  j=j+0.1;
end
```

MatLab only displays numbers 0-1.9. I expected to see numbers 0-2; what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @beaker Good catch. Although you've got close vote privileges, so go and use them :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not idiomatic MATLAB.

Idiomatic MATLAB looks like this:

---

```
% This is technically the same as your code, 
% so it should have suffered from exactly the same problem. 
% But thanks to rearrangement of calculation, 
% MATLAB will calculate the number of iterations is with a division,
% which gives ((20 - 0) / 0.1 + 1) == 201
% Because the result value of 201 is a "small" integer, 
% the IEEE floating-point rounding logic will cause the result's  
% representation to be exactly 201, and not some plus/minus epsilon.
%
% I have to emphasize this is not always the case; sometimes
% division can give not-exactly-integer results as well.
%
% This "almost, but not quite always" correct behavior led most 
% beginning MATLAB users into thinking that MATLAB is less susceptible 
% to the intricacies of finite-precision floating point arithmetics, 
% but OP's code example shows that MATLAB users must exercise 
% the same level of care as programmers of C.
%
for j = 0:0.1:20, 
    disp(j); 
end
```

---

```
% Integer index range is accurate up to `(2^53) - 1`
% beware of off-by-one.
idx = (0:200) * 0.1; 
for j = idx, 
    disp(j); 
end
```

---

```
% If you only care about the start, stop, 
% and the number of generated values.
% Beware of off-by-one.
idx = linspace(0, 20, 201); 
for j = idx, 
    disp(j); 
end
```

Comment: This is all true, but doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't produce the expected result.

Comment: i hope my answer addresses the specific question of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

the reason why it doesn't turn out the same is that base-2 floating-point numbers can represent 1 perfectly and precisely.  but they do not represent 0.1 precisely.  evidently the 0.1 value is represented a teeny-weeny bit high, like 0.10000000000000000001 so that when 0.10000000000000000001 is added to itself 20 times, it **exceeds** 2.0 (which is precisely represented) and therefore the test in the while loop fails in that last iteration where we would be expecting it to pass.